# Wordpress, get_posts does not returning all items with post_type=attachment

Tags: wordpress

I've some broken media files in wordpress database and need to wp_update_attachment_metadata. I like to call all id for post_type "attachment". I using the script below. I do not get all entries only around 1000. But if I query in MySql i get something arround 4000. My script should provide everything also listed in WP Media. I've tested the array and some media entries are missing. Where is my misunderstanding?

Thanks!!

```
$attachments = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'numberposts' => -1, 
        ));

return count($attachments);
```

My SQL Query to compare  the data are:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'attachment'
```

Comment: Why are you using `'post_status' => 'inherit'`? And if you query in MySql, do you select with a `WHERE` on `post_status` or do you just select all? Please share the SQL query you are talking about...

Comment: Also there's a duplicate key in your WP query array `'posts_per_page'`. I don't think that's causing the problem but it sure isn't helping..

Comment: Can you also put the `MySql` query in your question?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You are right with the double calls and the post_status flag, also 'numberposts' should not be needed. I've changed that. But I've tried a lot and there are answers in stackoverflow recommending to add the 'post_status'

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason for all the missing id's.

**First:** My issue was generated by the WPML plugin. In translating a post the plugin duplicates its media. (SVG's with empty attachment_metadata are duplicated and the issue was crowing.)

**Solution:** My "get_post call" contains only the post of the current language. After deactivating WPML I've had exactly the same counts like in my MySql query. So I was finally able to use wp_update_attachment_metadata for all corrupted images.